# Undefined reference errors in simple boost serialization

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, clion

I have a minimal example of Boost serialization where I try to save an integer in a binary archive file

Here is main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>

int main() {
    int t = 0;
    std::ofstream file("Test.bin");
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive archive(file);
    archive << t;
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(Test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED serialization)
add_executable(Test main.cpp)
if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(Test ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

When I try to run this program in CLion, I get a large list of undefined reference errors as shown here:
https://pastebin.com/8uX9MZFf

I have setup Boost using vcpkg package manager. I'm compiling using Mingw-w64. The CMake file loads without errors (only a warning that says "New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported targets," though I've heard this warning isn't of concern, as it just means the current version of CMake isn't aware of the newest version of Boost).

I've tried to look for solutions to this everywhere, but I can't seem to find anything that works here. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm using cmake 3.15.3, boost 1.73.0 and mingw-w64 6.0.

**EDIT**

I uninstalled and reinstalled Boost without using the package manager, and tried getting the serialization library again. In this context, CMake runs into errors saying it can't find Boost with serialization (Though it can find Boost alone). I set `Boost_DEBUG` to `ON` and looked at the output, and noticed the following things:

`_boost_COMPILER = "-mgw81" (guessed)`
CMake seems to guess that the compiler I used to compile boost was mgw81. I'm guessing it got the 8.1 from my gcc version, which is correct.

`Searching for SERIALIZATION_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_serialization-mgw81-mt-x64-1_73;boost_serialization-mgw81-mt-x64;...`

As a result of that compiler selection, it searches for a file with "-mgw81" in the name. The problem is that the library files generated when I built boost are named like so:

`libboost_serialization-mgw8-mt-x64-1_73.a`

This says "-mgw8" instead of "-mgw81". I don't know how to correct CMake or build boost in such a way that this conflict doesn't happen. I've tried rebuilding boost with `toolset=gcc-8.1` instead of `toolset=gcc`, but I still get "-mgw8" in the library file names.

**EDIT 2**

I found the solution to the above issue. I've posted it below.

Comment: Am I possibly misunderstanding something about how CMake works? I'm not doing any additional linking actions in "Build Options" or "CMake options" as I assume CMake does the linking through `target_link_libraries`

Comment: When building with the older (1.69) boost version, I get the final binary (`Test`) correctly linked with `libboost_serialization.so.1.69.0`.

Comment: With just what I have here? Like there are no additional steps taken to link that file? Also, did you build with the 64 bit mingw compiler? I suspect that the issue might be related to that.

Comment: I built with what you have there but with the 64 bit g++ version that comes with Fedora. I don't have MinGW unfortunately.

Comment: Could it be that you have a conflicting boost installation somewhere and that the warning is correct?

Comment: Hm yeah. I'm also not using standard mingw. I'm using the 64 bit compiler from http://mingw-w64.org/ . I'm also using the 64 bit version of boost.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214619/discussion-between-bhaskar-and-ted-lyngmo).

Comment: The way you are integrating Boost into CMake is an older, antiquated method, especially considering you are using fairly new versions of the software. Per the [`FindBoost`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/module/FindBoost.html) documentation, you should only need to use the imported target as such: `target_link_libraries(Test PRIVATE Boost::serialization)`

Comment: @squareskittles I changed the line to that, but the same error persists. It's still able to find Boost and the appropriate components, but when I run the program, I get those undefined reference errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After realizing that the issue was what I mentioned in **EDIT**, I looked further into how that issue could be resolved, and I found out you can manually set the compiler that is used to search through the variable `Boost_COMPILER`.

I changed my CMake file to the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(Test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH} "C:/boost_1_73_0")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} "C:/boost_1_73_0/libs")
set(Boost_DEBUG ON)
set(Boost_COMPILER -mgw8)
set(Boost_ARCHITECTURE -x64)
set(BOOST_ROOT C:/boost)
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR C:/boost/include/boost-1_73/boost)
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR C:/boost/lib)
set(BOOST_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS ON)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED serialization)
add_executable(Test main.cpp)
if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(Test ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

I believe the critical changes here were setting `Boost_COMPILER` and `Boost_ARCHITECTURE`. I realized `Boost_ARCHITECTURE` needed to be set from this question: [Linking boost in CLion project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58105485/linking-boost-in-clion-project?rq=1).

With this CMake file, my main.cpp file from above ran properly.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks for sharing this configuration edge-case. I'm sure it will help others a lot in the future.

Comment: why you have C:/boost_1_73_0  and C:/boost?